# Using File Api with Moodle Form to make files accessible from outside moodle project

Tags: php, forms, file, moodle

Need Help,

I have a deadline coming up and I am stuck in this,

I am totally lost while trying to do the following task: store file uploaded by user from moodle form and access (also download) it from a project outside moodle.

Detailed scenario :

A user will make requests by filling up the requests' form (request form is different for each type of request). User will have to upload following files from the moodle form: * Receipt * Supporting docs

Folders where the files need to be stored: On the server:

- `Uploads/Performa/Request_cardissuance/requestid.pdf`
- `Uploads/Performa/Request_degreeissuance/requestid.pdf` (Performa is the pdf form the of the request form)
- `Uploads/Receipt/Request_cardissuance/requestid.jpg`
- `Uploads/Receipt/Request_degreeissuance/requestid.jpg`
- `Uploads/Supporting_docs/Request_cardissuance/requestid.zip`
- `Uploads/Supporting_docs/Request_degreeissuance/requestid.zip`

A separate php project will have table:

`[ Sr. No | Request ID | Request Type ID | Performa | Receipt| Supporting Docs | Action|
1 | 1 | 1 | (link , when clicked downloads the pdf file)|do|do|action link ]`

I have Made the moodle form for it and added the filemanager element:

```
$mform->addElement('filemanager', 'receipt', get_string('receipt_file'), null,
                   array('maxbytes' => $CFG->maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => '*'));
```

What do I have to do in the view.php after this:

```
$fromform=$form->get_data() ;

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666572/how-to-store-a-file-in-moodle-so-that-it-is-accessible-for-an-external-applicati">this</a> is what I followed but I get a server error on calling function **get_new_filename()**
```

Using moodle v2.4.

Your Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Good luck in doing that. I've also spent a lot of time managing uploads in Moodle's plugins... eventually I've made my users use FTP to upload the files, and then they can get them from a File System Repository (http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/File_system_repository). Anyway, will the course, and the relative files, be available only for authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use the filepicker for each file rather than the filemanager. Then save the files into the folders above.

```
$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'receipt', get_string('receipt_file'), null,
               array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => '*'));
...
$id = $DB->insert_record(...)
$fullpath = "Uploads/Performa/Request_cardissuance/request{$id}.pdf";
$override = true;
$success = $mform->save_file('receipt', $fullpath, $override);
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#filepicker

I would recommend using a folder outside of the web root though, unless the documents are public?

Comment: Its not working. And yes thankyou for your recommendation, Ive created the folder outside web root